# Targeting people in astral via their activated foci?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5

Mage A has a activated focus on him and does not know about mage B since mage B is projecting and Mage A is not astraly perceiving. Can mage B use the activated focus of Mage A as a conductor to attack mage A with spells?

> While activated, a focus also has an astral form. p.318

To me it sounds obvious that you can target the focus but not necessarily the person carrying it. On the other hand the focus becomes part of the aura and is directly connected to the person. If it does not act as a conductor what happens to the focus if it is targeted by a combat spell in astral? Does it have a condition monitor? Can it be repaired?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SR5, but in SR1 & 2, it specifically says activated foci can be used to ground spells through.

Comment: @Adeptus: Those rules vanished. *Shadowrun 2050* it's mentioned that it ceased to work for unknown reasons. (But there are rules for grounding in that book) Note that I only know the German *Shadowrun 2050* book, which in contrast to the english version uses 5th edition rules.

Comment: @fabian: Interesting I wonder why it was changed. I don't really see anything broken or unfitting with it. But on the other hand I haven't read the 2050 Book and dont know how grounding works in it. Does it have similair effect or for what is it used?

Comment: It means you can use any dual natured being or activated focus as a "bridge" to cast physical spells from the astral plane. The magic rating or force of the "bridge" is a dice pool malus for spellcasting and drain is always physical. There is also some magic theoretical mumbo jumbo about the increased difficulty of transfering mana from one plane to the other... and a short passage that mentiones a "noncredible theory" that magic users stoped to use grounding because it gave them a "unfair advantage". I guess it's because (mystic) adepts without astral perception can't counterattack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes** and that is why you dont walk downstreet flaring in the astral with all your foci active, they draw attention and the bad kind of attention.
5ed, unlike the previous editions, wasnt able to explain that properly, but that kind of strategy is part of the setting, send someone on the astral plane to be the spotter, then cast some mana spell using a ritual with a few other guys to nuke that enemy.

They cannot, however, be targeted unless they are actively casting a spell or using a bound active focus.

Examples:

A) You cannot astrally attack a mage that has no spells or foci active.

B) You cannot attack someone using a focus katana if he isnt the person bound to it, as they get no benefit from it other than it being a sharp katana.

C) Complementing #B, you cant attack the person bound to the same katana, as simply being carried by someone doesnt make it "activated", even if someone else is using it in combat.

D) You could even ready an action while following someone to cast a spell as soon as that person flares in the astral plane.

E) People on the astral can also attack you while you are astrally perceiving, because you will also flare in the astral while looking at it.

PS: That also works for your enemies, they can do all kind of nasty stuff to you. So, never, EVER, leave mana trails behind. Takes only a few minutes to remove your signature from an area where you cast your spells, and will save you from ages of headaches.

Now to your other question:
Yes it can be targeted, but follow the normal rules for attacking objects. If you destroy the object, the foci is destroyed aswell, as their astral-physical connection is severed.

For general astral rules: page 312-315 5ed core rulebook.
For foci and astral auras: page 318 5ed core rulebook.
About Physical vs Mana Spells and Astral beings: page 282 5ed core rulebook.
About how to fight astral enemies: page 361 5ed core rulebook.
All those references are further explored on magical sourcebooks from previous editions.

Comment: Thank you I think this ruling makes the game more interesting. May I ask did you just make up those rules or do you have a source for them?

Comment: The source are the various source books from 2nd, 3rd and 4th edition (5ed briefly mentions it), but i will compile a page reference list for you.

Comment: Edited my answer with the book references.

For general astral rules: page 312-315 5ed core rulebook.  
For foci and astral auras: page 318 5ed core rulebook.  
About Physical vs Mana Spells and Astral beings: page 282 5ed core rulebook.  
About how to fight astral enemies: page 361 5ed core rulebook.  
All those references are further explored on magical sourcebooks from previous editions.